# How can I get a .sh file to run as Sudo in profile.d?

Tags: 14.04, sudo, root, .sh

I have a .sh script that needs to run to check if a machine has had certain parameters set. I've placed it in the profile.d directory but I need this script to run with sudo privilege.

Does anyone know if this is possible and how to go about it? I'm running 14.04 server (no GUI).

Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like it might be [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - what is your end goal here, exactly?

Comment: To have my .sh file run when anyone logs in with sudo privilege.

Answer (score 0):

If you set it's permissions to +s, as in `sudo chown root:rootfile ; sudo chmod +s file` you will see it set to 6664/-rwSrwSr-- permissions.

This sets the user to root, & makes it executable.

A degree of caution is merited when doing this!

Comment: I tried this but when I log in and the script runs, it's still not running as sudo and therefore unable to commit any changes.